# RTMFP with Flash Media Interactive Server

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, rtmfp

Only the Flash Media Enterprise Server(FMES) has the "RTMFP peer introduction services"
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/compare/

influxis created SmartMesh which enables p2p in Flash Media Interactive Server(FMiS).
http://labs.influxis.com/?p=1253&cpage=1#comment-54661

I couldn't find info on what does the peer introduction service do
, what is the difference in capabilities of FMiS and FMES
and what is the difference between RTMFP unicast and RMTFP multicast.

Is it possible to create a p2p rtmfp connection between two clients with FMiS
assuming I have a webservice that help clients exchange FarID?
Can you explain how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't - because to get client.farID you need a server, which would accept a rtmfp://your_server connection, and FMIS won't do it.